# Using cat in a bash script : escaping troubles

Tags: bash, escaping, echo, cat

I'm very bad at regex and escaping characters.
I want to use the 'cat' command in a bash script like this :

```
echo `cat working-dir/*OUTPUT` ;
```

That should print on screen, every files in the working-dir that end with "OUTPUT" but this is not working

Later in that program, i would like to do this :

```
cat working-dir/*OUTPUT >> result_file.txt
```

But is not working either :(
Can you help me please?

Comment: Backticks are not quotes; you could fix this by using `echo "$(cat working-sir/*OUTPUT)"`, but the `echo` itself is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using echo, or backticks, at all?

```
cat working-dir/*OUTPUT
```

Similarly,

```
cat working-dir/*OUTPUT >> result_file.txt
```

...certainly should work. Please provide a complete script for reproducing any failure that you see, including setup (creating working-dir, putting at least one file ending with OUTPUT into it, running the cat, and observing it to fail).

Comment: I feel so stupid. I searched for something too complicated... Thanks !

Comment: @JohnKugelman No, it won't work (in the sense of emitting output verbatim) -- it performs string-splitting and glob-expansion. Thus, if an `OUTPUT` file contained newlines, they would be transformed to spaces; if it contained a `*`, it would be replaced with a list of filenames; etc. Correcting this would require correcting the quoting.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I don't know exactly what you mean by "extra", but unquoted expansions certainly do glob-expand. Try creating a file containing only a `*` character and testing it yourself.